# error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token '<', expected ';'

Tags: c++

using VS2017 and the code:

```
template <typename T>
void showset(vector<T> v)
{
    for (vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

the error is :

> error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token , expected ';'

The question is how to use the iterator of template

Comment: Try `typename vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin();` instead, or `auto it = v.begin();`.

Comment: Also, pass big objects such as containers not by value, but by const-reference: `void showset(const vector<T>& v)`.

Answer (score 6):

First note that if referring to a [template argument dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) like `vector<T>::iterator` here, then you need to put `typename` prior. Furthermore, depends on what `T` is, this would only compile if `std::cout`'s `operator<<` is accepting this `T`. This, for example, compiles just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void showset(std::vector<T> v)
{
    for (typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

struct foo
{
};

int main()
{
    showset(std::vector<int>{1,2,3});
    //showset(std::vector<foo>{}); // Error: `cout` doesn't take `foo`s.

    return 0;
}
```

With the [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)-enhanced syntax of C++11, `showset()` could be written like this, and then the `typename` has no use : )

```
template <typename T>
void showset(std::vector<T> v)
{
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Also since C++11, you can use the [range-based *for* loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to achieve the same as in your original snippet:

```
template <typename T>
void showset(std::vector<T> v)
{
    for (auto& ref : v)
    {
        std::cout << ref;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

As with the lase version, because you're not referring here to the `iterator` type there's nothing to put `typename` for.

---

Do note that in both versions you are taking parameter `v` by value. Hence, you're copying the entire vector for each function call. As the code is given in the question, there seem to be no reason for this and so you should be passing it by reference, and make it a `const` one too as you're not modifying `v` anywhere inside of `showset()`:

```
void showset(const std::vector<T>& v);
```

and then in the non-*range-based for loop* version don't forget to change the  loop statement accordingly:

```
for (typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
```

Comment: @Bllue If you're wondering why not put `using namespace std;` you're welcome to read about it [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2):

The good aproch to this looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
void showset(const T& v)
{
    for (auto const &x : v)
    {
        cout << x;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Or without range loop:

```
template <typename T>
void showset(const T& v)
{
    for (auto it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

**Edit**:
But I'm usually using something more complex. More or less it looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class LogContainerHelper {
    LogContainerHelper(const T& v
                       size_t maxFront,
                       size_t maxTail)
        : mContainer{ v }
        , mMaxFront{ maxFront }
        , mMaxTail{ maxTail }
    {}

    std::ostream &printTo(std::ostream &out) const {
         // here I usually have something more complex
         // depending on mMaxFront and mMaxTail values, 
         // don't have time to recreate that now
         auto it = std::begin(mContainer);
         auto end = std::end(mContainer);

         out << '[';
         if (it != end) {
            out << *it;
            ++it;
         }
         for (; it != end; ++it)
         {
             out << ", " << *it;
         }
         return out << ']';
    }
private:
    const T &mContainer;
    size_t mMaxFront;
    size_t mMaxTail;
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const LogContainerHelper<T> &helper) {
    return helper.printTo(out);
}

template<typename T>
auto LogContainer(const T& v,
                  size_t maxFront = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(),
                  size_t maxTail = 0)
        -> LogContainerHelper<T> {
    return LogContainerHelper<T>{ v, maxFront, maxTail };
}
```

So later I can do that:

```
 cout << "Main containter is: " << LogContainer(v) << '\n';
```

Comment: This is not the same as the OP's `void showset(vector<T> v)`

Comment: yes and it is on purpose. This is more universal, it works with any container.

Comment: I agree it's more universal, just saying this *universality* may not have been what the OP has intended for. A restriction is also a feature if desired. At least nothing comes to my mind so far as to where he specified it is not the case.